# Slow Connection to Server (100kb/s) on all Protocols (HTTP/SSH/FTP)

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, nginx

We have been experiencing an intermittent problem with our server (1gb port) which sporadically will only serve files at a maximum speed of 100kb/s via all protocols (HTTP/FTP/SSH).

First we thought that maybe this was the Web Server but we ruled that out after realizing that even SSH connections are being capped.

We did a speed test from the server and upload speeds would occasionally fluctuate from 5mbit/s - 300mbit/s! They are normally around 300mbit/s but even at those speeds incoming connections to the server still experience sporadic periods where connections are capped at 100kb/s.

We asked our datacenter to investigate and they claimed they found no issues with the network connection (unusual as no idea what else would be causing our uploads speeds to fluctuate so drastically).

What could possibly be causing connections to get capped at 100kb/s?? It doesn't appear to be the web server or firewall.

Could we possible be under a DDoS attack?

The server gets a lot of traffic but is not under heavy load and it has been working fine for the past 2 years and we have not had any recent spikes in traffic. Only within the past 2 weeks has this intermittent problem started and we are scratching our heads to figure out what the cause might be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was some bad routing going on from my ISP to the server that was apparently resulting in the connection being capped at 100kb/s.

The datacenter was aware of an issue with the traffic from my ISP and suggested that I get rerouted.

I switched my local machine's public IP to a different subnet which ultimately got me a different path to the server which resolved the issue.

Bi-direction iperf tests are recommended to help establish which side the connection issues are on.

Though, it makes me wonder how many users might have been effected and what the extent of the issue is because we had been receiving a lot of complaints about slow connections and were even experiencing it ourselves. I was able to resolve it by changing my IP but many users don't know how to do that or how to get rerouted or what that even means.

Comment: Then there isn't much you can do about this except start load-balancing or move to cloud. Perhaps find secondary datacenter which isn't behind the ISP bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

1. Some "datacenters" offer the gigabit connection shared between several servers. Thus when others transfer a lot of data, your connection speed will decrease. First verify your plan details - that you indeed have guaranteed 1 gigabit speed at all times.
2. DDoS cannot be ruled out - but datacenters generally can identify and block this kind of traffic - so they should know.
3. Make sure that it's not the second location experiencing these fluctuations (the one from which you perform the bandwidth tests).
4. Monitor incoming and outgoing traffic (eg. tcpdump on linux). Search if you can spot any patterns matching the periods with slower connection speed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like it turned out to be #3 and my ISP was likely to blame for bad routing to the server.